# Snakemake: trimmomatic wrapper attribute error

Tags: python, snakemake

I have a snakemake pipeline that looks like this:

```
configfile: "./config.yaml"
IN_DIR = config["in_dir"]
SAMPLES = config["samples"]

rule all:
    input: 
        expand("{sample}_Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam", sample=SAMPLES)

rule trimmomatic_pe:
    message:
        """
        Pre-processing raw reads with trimmomatic. Trimming low quality reads and adapter sequences. Running QC on trimmed reads.
        """
    input:
        r1 = expand("{in_dir}/{{sample}}_R1_001.fastq.gz", in_dir=IN_DIR),
        r2 = expand("{in_dir}/{{sample}}_R2_001.fastq.gz", in_dir=IN_DIR)
    params:
        trimmer = config["parameters"]["trim"],
        extra = ""
    output:
        r1 = "tmp/{sample}_R1_trimmed.fastq.gz",
        r2 = "tmp/{sample}_R2_trimmed.fastq.gz",
        r1_unpaired = "tmp/{sample}_R1_unpaired_trimmed.fastq.gz",
        r2_unpaired = "tmp/{sample}_R2_unpaired_trimmed.fastq.gz"
    threads:
        2
    wrapper:
        "0.74.0/bio/trimmomatic/pe"

rule map_reads:
    message:
        """
        Mapping trimmed reads to host genome
        """
    input:
        r1 = "tmp/{sample}_R1_trimmed.fastq.gz",
        r2 = "tmp/{sample}_R2_trimmed.fastq.gz"
    params:
        annotation = config["annotation_file"]
    output:
        "{sample}_Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam"
    shell:
        """
        STAR \
            --runThreadN 16 \
            --sjdbGTFfile {params.annotation} \
            --sjdbOverhang 149 \
            --outFilterType BySJout \
            --outFilterMultimapNmax 10 \
            --alignSJoverhangMin 5 \
            --alignSJDBoverhangMin 1 \
            --outFilterMismatchNmax 999 \
            --outFilterMismatchNoverReadLmax 0.04 \
            --alignIntronMin 20 \
            --alignIntronMax 1000000 \
            --alignMatesGapMax 1000000 \
            --outFilterIntronMotifs RemoveNoncanonicalUnannotated \
            --outFileNamePrefix {wildcards.sample}_ \
            --outSAMtype BAM SortedByCoordinate \
            --runMode alignReads \
            --genomeDir ./index \
            --readFilesIn {input.r1} {input.r2}
        """
```

When I run `snakemake -np` the DAG is correctly made, but I keep getting this error that I don't know how to interpret when I try to actually run the pipeline with `snakemake --cores 2`:

```
[Thu Apr 29 15:12:21 2021]
Job 1: 
        Pre-processing raw reads with trimmomatic. Trimming low quality reads and adapter sequences. Running QC on trimmed reads.
        

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Documents/postdoc_projects/invert/.snakemake/scripts/tmp7yzyzwru.wrapper.py", line 88, in <module>
    input_files, output_files, snakemake.threads
  File "/Users/user/Documents/postdoc_projects/invert/.snakemake/scripts/tmp7yzyzwru.wrapper.py", line 27, in distribute_threads
    gzipped_input_files = sum(1 for file in input_files if file.endswith(".gz"))
  File "/Users/user/Documents/postdoc_projects/invert/.snakemake/scripts/tmp7yzyzwru.wrapper.py", line 27, in <genexpr>
    gzipped_input_files = sum(1 for file in input_files if file.endswith(".gz"))
AttributeError: 'Namedlist' object has no attribute 'endswith'
[Thu Apr 29 15:12:22 2021]
Error in rule trimmomatic_pe:
    jobid: 1
    output: tmp/4_12hr_Ciliated_4_S4_R1_trimmed.fastq.gz, tmp/4_12hr_Ciliated_4_S4_R2_trimmed.fastq.gz, tmp/4_12hr_Ciliated_4_S4_R1_unpaired_trimmed.fastq.gz, tmp/4_12hr_Ciliated_4_S4_R2_unpaired_trimmed.fastq.gz

RuleException:
CalledProcessError in line 29 of /Users/user/Documents/postdoc_projects/invert/Snakefile:
Command 'set -euo pipefail;  /Users/user/opt/miniconda3/envs/invert/bin/python3.6 /Users/user/Documents/postdoc_projects/invert/.snakemake/scripts/tmp7yzyzwru.wrapper.py' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  File "/Users/user/Documents/postdoc_projects/invert/Snakefile", line 29, in __rule_trimmomatic_pe
  File "/Users/user/opt/miniconda3/envs/invert/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

Is the pipeline not identifying my sample correctly? The attribute error seems like that's the case, but this is my config file structure:

```
in_dir: data #Directory containing raw fastq files from RNAseq
samples: "4_12hr_Ciliated_4_S4" #sample name prefix
annotation_file: ref_files/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.103.gtf #Directory containing the viral host genome annotation in .gtf format

parameters:
  trim: ["TRAILING:3 ILLUMINACLIP:ref_files/TruSeq3-PE-2.fa"] #trimmomatic parameters
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `expand` function returns a list.  By setting the input files to a list instead of a string, you are confusing the script. For defining r1 and r2, you should use something that returns a string instead. I would suggest the string's `format()` function or an f-string.

Change:

```
r1 = expand("{in_dir}/{{sample}}_R1_001.fastq.gz", in_dir=IN_DIR),
```

to:

```
r1 = "{in_dir}/{{sample}}_R1_001.fastq.gz".format(in_dir=IN_DIR),
```

or even:

```
r1 = f"{IN_DIR}/{{sample}}_R1_001.fastq.gz",
```

...and do the same for r2